# UINavigationController flow for login ios

Tags: ios, objective-c

**Solved:**

once the user has logged in / signed up, use the following code to transition to the main storyboard...

```
 UIWindow* window = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];

 window.rootViewController = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] instantiateInitialViewController];
```

I have the following UINavigationController flow to handle logging in...the top segue after the tabbarcontroller goes to a uinavigationcontroller that is the root for a viewcontroller.

[image]

When the user is already logged in the "this segue works" is executed so that the user doesn't have to log in at the login screen. That works perfectly. The issue I run into is when the user has to login...the segue from the login/signup screen to the login screen works perfectly, but when I go from the login screen to the tabbar the following happens:

[image]

This really shouldn't happen because I have the following code in my viewcontroller.m (gotten to here is called)

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    ...
    self.navigationItem.title = @"Messages";
    self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;

    NSLog(@"gotten to here");
    ...
}
```

Does anybody know why this is happening?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I like to keep my login flow separate from the normal app flow. This means that I don't link a segue from the login screen to the app, but I handle that in my AppDelegate:

```
if ([MyUserHandler sharedHelper].isAuthenticated) {
    [self presentMainInterface];
} else {
    [self presentWelcomeInterface];
}
```

Where the first method does this:

```
- (void)presentMainInterface
{
    self.window.rootViewController = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] instantiateInitialViewController];
}
```

and the other presents the login screen:

```
- (void)presentWelcomeInterface
{   
    UIViewController* rootController = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"loginScreen"];

    UINavigationController* navigation = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:rootController];
    self.window.rootViewController = navigation;
}
```

This way the login screen is loaded only when the user is not authenticated.

Comment: and then when the user logs in, how do you instantiate the main interface? with self.window.rootViewController = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] instantiateInitialViewController];

Comment: Once the user logs in I just call the same method, presentMainInterface. It will switch the rootviewcontroller of the window, showing the main interface.

Answer (score 0):

Make a custom class (sub class) of UITabBarControler and assign that custom class for your tabbarcontroller in storyboard. Then In viewDidLoad of custom tabbarcontroller add your code

```
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
```

It will work fine.

[image]

Comment: Make sure to disable also the swipe gesture: 
    self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.enabled = NO;

Comment: Then it may be some other issue. I have tested this in a demo before posting here. It works well.